# Implementation of call/cc or its analog in Mathematica

Tags: procedural-programming

*BACKGROUND*

- [call/cc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) is commonly used by lisp-like languages as a [control flow operator](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16353/65089). And mathematica can also be seen as a lisp-like language.

*QUESTION*

1. How to complete implement `call/cc` in mathematica? (Please use Scheme's `call/cc` as a baseline)
2. We can easily write the law of excluded middle (`LEM`) in mathematica. Can we have a complete implementation of `call/cc` with just this `LEM`?

> like: `P || ! P`, `P || False`, `Forall[P, (P || ! P)]`, `Forall[P, (P || False)]` ... All of the above can be considered `LEM` implementations (and they are not `Equivalent` to `True` in mathematica)

3. Can we implement `call/cc` without using mathematica's own control flow operators at all, and then use `call/cc` to implement mathematica's own [control flow operators](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16353/65089)?

Comment: You are assuming that we know what `call/cc` means/does as well as what `the law of excluded middle` means. Edit your question to explain these or, at a minimum, provide links to something that defines/explains what is meant.

Comment: @BobHanlon The requested additional clarifications have been made.